# Mac OS X not booting

Tags: macos, mac, windows-7

I have dual booted my laptop with Mac OS X and Windows 7 (hackintosh) . It was working fine for some days.
But now, Windows 7 gets started properly.. But Mac OS does not boot. I can't even see the loading screen with the icon of Apple.
What might be the problem? Any idea? please help...

Comment: Your computer is a Mac and you installed Windows or your computer is a PC and you installed MacOSX?

Comment: @Murilo, Hackintosh ...

Comment: [Hackintosh as such falls in a legal grey area](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1381/banned-tag-proposal-hackintosh), and hence Hackintosh related questions are not entertained on Super User.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the fact that this is a Hackintosh. These are against the OS X Software License Agreement.

> Subject to the terms and conditions of this License, unless you have purchased a Family Pack or Upgrade license for the Apple Software, 
>   you are granted a limited non-exclusive license to install, use and run one (1) copy of the Apple Software on a **single Apple-branded computer** at a time. You 
>   agree not to install, use or run the Apple Software on any non-Apple-branded computer, or to enable others to do so. This License does not allow the Apple 
>   Software to exist on more than one computer at a time, and you may not make the Apple Software available over a network where it could be used by multiple 
>   computers at the same time.

And, since the hardware isn't compatible with OS X, there could be any number of issues with this. In short, the issue you're having is because this is a Hackintosh.